# Single Sign-On using ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I'm looking at using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for our multi app, multi sites single sign-on.  Previously I have tried working with Thinktecture IdentityServer with MembershipReboot but getting the two married cleanly is becoming a difficult task.  Each does their thing well separate but we're left to our own if we want to integrate.

Is it possible now to create an ASP.NET Identity 2.0 MVC app that manages users and passwords for multi domain sites?  It seems like the key bits are still in beta.

Note:  we'll store in a SQL database and not in Azure or AD

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as long as you are sharing the same datasource for membership. You may be able to create a separate DB for membership that is accessible by all these apps/websites.

Comment: I do want to use the same DB. Any docs or samples you can point me to?

Comment: Have you read this resource :
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: The caveat is that there is no way to in the current membership implementation to specify separate users for each site.